# What application account do console applications run as in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, console-application

My console application does not have read/write access to a set of files in my system. Therefore, I need to know what application account they are using so I can give that account proper permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Windows and Console applications run as the user that invoked them.
If UAC is enabled, they will not run with administrative privileges unless you right-click and click Run as Administrator. (you can force this in the manifest)